# AdSense giving error Valuable Inventory : No Content to my website

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, adsense

I have built flutter website [www.droidbiz.in](https://www.droidbiz.in) I have applied to AdSense and they are giving me following error:

**Valuable Inventory: No content**

**We do not allow monetization where there is no content.**

**No content includes placeholder content for sites or apps under construction.****

Does AdSense supports flutter website? How can I fix this issue?

Is there any other monetization techniques available for flutter web?

Comment: might help you: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-resolve-Valuable-Inventory-Under-Construction-in-Google-AdSense

Comment: AdSense does support flutter, its not working due to the messages in the error. This question is better suited for other communities as it does not relate to a programming related problem.

Comment: @RohanThacker "its not working due to the messages in the error." i did not understood from this line. Can u please explain which error are you talking about? Thanks for response.

Comment: The message in the question. *No content includes placeholder content for sites or apps under construction.*

Comment: @RohanThacker I have asked to AdSense community about this error and they have given reply that my website not approved because AdSense can not run javascript so can not see any content. So i need to enable server side rendering. So what can be issue in my website. Still i am not able to find solution.

Comment: I'm not sure...To be honest with you flutter is not the best for SEO and Ad's right now because of these problems

Comment: @RohanThacker I have implemented SEO in my website and i am getting good traffic. So SEO is working properly for my website. But i don't know what is issue with AdSense. Because my website has many pages with good amount of content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234598/discussion-between-rohan-thacker-and-rashmi-tank).